# Группировка записей из цикла под спойлером и открытие спойлера при клике на конкретный элемент

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Ребята, ломаю голову уже не первый день над такой проблемой. В цикле есть данные, которые я скрываю под спойлером, если они похожи по группе. Пример того что есть в данный момент:

```js
var d = $(document),
  groupBlock = "",
  el = "",
  count;

$("[data-group]").each(function() {
  el = $(this);

  if (el.data("group")) {
    groupBlock = d.find(".cont-" + el.data("group"));
    count = d.find("[data-group=" + el.data("group") + "]").length;

    if (groupBlock.length) {
      el.appendTo(groupBlock);
    } else {
      if (count > 1) {
        el.append("<div class=\'block cont-" + el.data("group") + "\' style=\'display:none;\'></div>").addClass("first")
      }
    }
  }

}).on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).find("div.block").stop().slideToggle();
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

```css
.block {
  display: none;
}
.first {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-group="0">
  <div class="cardline">
    <div class="cardgroup" style="float:left;">group 0</div>
    <div class="cardname" style="float:left;">name 0</div>
    <div class="cardlogo" style="float:left;">logo 0</div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-group="1">
  <div class="cardline">
    <div class="cardgroup" style="float:left;">group 1</div>
    <div class="cardname" style="float:left;">name 1</div>
    <div class="cardlogo" style="float:left;">logo 1</div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-group="1">
  <div class="cardline">
    <div class="cardgroup" style="float:left;">group 1 child</div>
    <div class="cardname" style="float:left;">name 1 child</div>
    <div class="cardlogo" style="float:left;">logo 1 child</div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Все работает корректно, но задача такова. Если я нажму на вторую строку, где у нас group 1 name 1 logo 1 - откроется спойлер. Вопрос состоит в том, что бы спойлер открывался тогда, когда мы нажимаем на такой элемент как logo 1, к примеру.

Я себе вижу это так, что можно попробовать узнать имя класса, при клике на элемент, и если это класc *cardlogo* - то тогда открыть спойлер. Однако, у меня никак не получается корректно получить имя класса, так как *cardlogo* дочерний класс *cardline*.

Comment: P.S. прошу все же перейти по ссылке на jsfiddle и посмотреть пример

Comment: `html`, это прежде всего компоненты, которые обязаны быть спроектированы по всем законам программирования. Ничего страшного если верховный элемент-контейнер будет обладать данными схожими со своими детьми. Это лучше чем потрошить и ковыряться внутри. Но ещё лучше подходить во все оружие к проектированию, даже как бы это смешно не казалось, к проектирования `html`. Хотя ничего смешного и нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, если я правильно понимаю, вы хотите...

Привязать `click` к `.cardlogo`?

```js
var d = $(document),
  groupBlock = "",
  el = "",
  count;

$("[data-group]").each(function() {
  el = $(this);

  if (el.data("group")) {
    groupBlock = d.find(".cont-" + el.data("group"));
    count = d.find("[data-group=" + el.data("group") + "]").length;

    if (groupBlock.length) {
      el.appendTo(groupBlock);
    } else {
      if (count > 1) {
        el.append("<div class=\'block cont-" + el.data("group") + "\' style=\'display:none;\'></div>").addClass("first")
      }
    }
  }

})/**/.find('.cardlogo')/**/.on('click', function(e) {
  $(this)/**/.closest("[data-group]")/**/.find("div.block").stop().slideToggle();
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

```css
.block {
  display: none;
}
.first {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-group="0">
  <div class="cardline">
    <div class="cardgroup" style="float:left;">group 0</div>
    <div class="cardname" style="float:left;">name 0</div>
    <div class="cardlogo" style="float:left;">logo 0</div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-group="1">
  <div class="cardline">
    <div class="cardgroup" style="float:left;">group 1</div>
    <div class="cardname" style="float:left;">name 1</div>
    <div class="cardlogo" style="float:left;">logo 1</div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-group="1">
  <div class="cardline">
    <div class="cardgroup" style="float:left;">group 1 child</div>
    <div class="cardname" style="float:left;">name 1 child</div>
    <div class="cardlogo" style="float:left;">logo 1 child</div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Божественно! Спасибо Вам большое! Все работает как надо)